# Background Intelligent Transfer Service In C#

Tags: c#, upload, download, file-transfer, microsoft-bits

Anyone successfully using this in c# or is there a better alternative to this? Also any good working project that I can look at and get a good feel? most projects i have come across is in C++ and was looking for a C# project

Answer (score 12):

Yes, we're using it in a tool to let customers upload logs, dumps, etc. to our customer support department. You could use it directly via PInvoke/COMInterop, but I suggest to have a look at [SharpBITS.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpbits), which wraps the BITS interface nicely.

Comment: Hey Martin,
I would appreciate if you could you put any comments on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830811/using-clickonce-deployment-with-background-intelligent-transfer-service.

Comment: I know that this is a very old thread but was wondering if there are any alternatives to SharpBITS as it looks to be dead and was last updated in 2011

Comment: Try the [Windows.Bits](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows.Bits/) NuGet package. It looks to be the most alive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the PM for the BITS team at Microsoft -- and we have a new [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bits-dot-net) page that talks about using BITS and C#, plus a brand-new C#/WPF sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/bits-manager).

Comment: We have an implementation that uses ComImport as I believe the old documentation specified. Is there a benefit to using MIDL and TLBIMP? Currently we have an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457118/bits-an-error-occurred-in-the-secure-channel-support) with BITS/WinHttp on Windows 7 defaulting to TLS 1.0, which only seems to be fixable by a registry change - one that I cannot force on my customer computers.