# .NET 3.5 Download Large Files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, download, microsoft-bits

I want to allow users to download a large file - around 4GB.  I'd like them to have the ability to resume failed downloads.

Can anyone make any recommendations on the best way to do this?  Or are there any off the shelf components out there that ppl have had success with?

I'm using IIS7 to host the app.

I've seen a few approaches out there, but they're all quite old.

Cheers,
David.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your uses utilize a download manager like the [MS File Transfer Manager](http://transfers.ds.microsoft.com/ftm/default.aspx?target=home) or [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) or you could roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my post [ASP.NET Web API file download service with resume support](http://www.piotrwalat.net/file-download-service-with-resume-support-using-asp-net-web-api/)

It shows how to implement file download service in Web API that supports pause/resume. You can pick one of two approaches presented there - either a FileStream wrapper or memory-mapped files (this one will work only your app can run as 64bit). Both should support arbitrarily large files.

Using Web API gives you additional benefit of being able to host the service in windows service or 'normal' .net applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

[BITS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits)

[Background Intelligent Transfer-Service in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397718/background-intelligent-transfer-service-in-c)