# Uploading Large Files

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-bits

I'm using a windows service on my server to receive large files (1 GB) from desktop clients when I use the TCPClient class it creates astream to send the file which bloks my memory, What is the well designe for this problem

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the Microsoft Background Intelligent Transfer Service as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397718/background-intelligent-transfer-service-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

The file should be segmented, then the method should send each segment apart, while loading the segments into the memory on-demand.

It might be that using [My.Computer.Network.UploadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfkdh7eb.aspx) will provide you a better, already-written, upload method.