# .Net library for split volume zip files?

Tags: c#, zip

I need to create spanned (multi-volume) zip files using .Net, but I have been unable to find a library  that enables me to do it.

Spanned zip is a zip compressed file that is split among a number of files, which usually have extensions like .z00, .z01, and so on.

The library would have to be open-source or free, because I'm gonna use it for a open source project.

(it's a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288548/split-zip-file-using-dotnetzip-library) question, but there are no answers there and I'm not going for ASP specific anyway)

Comment: Years later, but just to clarify this question is about split archives. Spanned zip archives are something else entirely - single ZIP archives split across multiple logical volumes (generally designed around floppy disks). The difference is that a split ZIP archive uses the ".z00 - .z(n - 1)" naming whereas in a spanned archive all of the files share the same name (with the same ".zip" extension).

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[DotNetZip](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/) allows you to do this. From their documentation:

> The library supports zip passwords, Unicode, ZIP64, stream input and output,
> AES encryption, multiple compression levels, self-extracting archives,
> spanned archives, and more.

Comment: dotNetZip has a max number of spanned file = 99.if you want to make a 15mb files (to send to email) and the zipped stuff are > ~ 1.5GB you are out of luck.

Comment: It is true that DotNetZip has a maximum file (segment) count of 99 for split archives, though this seems to be entirely arbitrary. The earliest revision I can find (Wikipedia) that specifies a limit is 6.3.0 (2006), which matches 6.3.4 (2014) in a ~4 billion file limit (http://goo.gl/vh4Sp5 - Section 8.5.1). However, since the library is open-source, you could at the very least create a custom modification of it. With a minimum file size of 64K (per ZIP specification), you could have roughly 256 TB in one split ZIP archive without going over the file limit.

Comment: There was a pull request merged in 2014 that removed the 99 file limit.  I can confirm that there is no more file limit

Answer (score 31):

DotNetZip example:

```
int segmentsCreated ;
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.UseUnicode= true;  // utf-8
  zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX");
  zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ;
  zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 100*1024 ; // 100k segments
  zip.Save("MyFiles.zip");

  segmentsCreated = zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave ;
}
```

if `segmentsCreated` comes back as 5, then you have the following files, each not more than 100kb in size.

- MyFiles.zip
- MyFiles.z01
- MyFiles.z02
- MyFiles.z03
- MyFiles.z04

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex][1]. It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---

Comment: nice code but do not understand this line `zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 100*1024` how does it mean 100 kb ? i guess u try to say 1024Byte means 1KB and 1KB*100 means 100 KB.....am i right ?

Comment: Hey guys ! Once the folder is splitted into multiple segments, how do you put them back together to unzip them and have the initial content ?
In your example, how do you read the 5 zip files (MyFiles.zip, MyFiles.z01, MyFiles.z02, MyFiles.Z03 and MyFiles.z04) to get the initial directory ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [SevenZipSharp](https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp/) library.  It supports multivolumes archives.