# How to limit the size of generated ZIPs?

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib, filesplitting

I'm using :

```
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip z = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip();
```

So i'm generating a zip regarding a folder. This folder contains several files.

```
z.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;
z.CreateZip("Temp.zip", directory, true, "");
```

What I want is limit the size of the zips at 50Mo.

If the size of a zip if more than 50Mo then I want to generate an other zip with the others files.

For example I have :

```
Zip_1.zip SIze : 50Mo
Zip_2.zip Size : 50Mo
Zip_3.zip SIze : 34Mo
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: I do not think this is possible with SharpZipLib, See [.Net library for split volume zip-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671811/net-library-for-split-volume-zip-files)

Comment: It don t answer my issue. It generates several files with one principal zip. But what I Want is store in several zip the files. Limit at 50Mo.

Comment: and what is it supposed to do if a file is larger than 50MB? If you know files are smaller than some amount you could just add files until the archive is ~50MB and start the next one.